# Unable to Renew apple developer program in mac book pro developer app

Tags: ios, macos, apple-m1

[image]

After clicking renew button it is showing the below error please help me to solve this issue. I'm trying to pay the payment for last 2 days. But I could not. My mac os version is `13.2 (22D49)`.

[image]

Comment: Have you enabled 2FA on your Apple ID? Do you have any outstanding agreements to accept at https://developer.Apple.com? Have you contacted Apple developer support?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/33257?answerId=737548022#737548022

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/717139

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed in `Apple Developer` app version 10.3.

Clicked again on `Renew` button after update and I am no longer getting above `Unable to Continue` popup.

Also received mail from Apple Developer Program Support team. Adding screenshot below :

[image]